# How to find out in Xtend if an optional feature from an Xtext grammar is used or not?

Tags: grammar, dsl, xtext, xtend, mde

I have the following xtext fragments:

```
LongDmxColor:
    intensity=DmxValue red=DmxValue green=DmxValue blue=DmxValue (white=DmxValue)?;
```

and

```
DmxValue returns INT:
    value=INT;
```

In the generated LongDmxColor.java class, there are the following methods related to white:

```
INT getWhite();
void setWhite(INT value);
```

How can I in xtend find out whether white is selected or not?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (to help others):

Use the `eIsSet` command, like:

```
if (colorItem.eIsSet(DmxLightShowPackage.Literals.LONG_DMX_COLOR__WHITE))
```